# How to disable codeigniter database select query errors?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have a situation. I have a forloop, inside it, gets orders from database using multiple queries. The problem is, even if one query fails the entire execution halts. I want the execution to continue, even after a select query fails and displays error. Any help, would be appreciated??

Comment: Can you post a code snippet so we can see what you're working with? I feel like making suggestions but fear they may not make any sense unless I can see a bit more of what's going on.

Comment: Using a forloop to pull orders out a db with multiple queries sounds to me like a design error.. Can you post the table structures, example data (place it on db-fiddle.com) and the PHP code? And expected results.

Comment: You can set `$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;` in your database conf, you can suppress the error with `@`, or you can simply check the results `if($query->result)` etc...